# Firebase session token length Issue

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am having, from what it seems, an token issue using Firebase. Since moving to Firebase from parse, I am seeing both Android and iOS users being kicked off after some time. I can't seem to understand what could be causing it other than the firebase token expiring and not making a new one. Any ideas how I could go about this? Could an issue be caused from the "rules" I set up?

Comment: Firebase uses a combination of long-lived and short-lived tokens. The latter should be auto-refreshed. Without seeing the [minimum code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to say more.

Comment: There was a token timeout setting in the legacy console. Did this make it over to the new console?

Comment: @dazza5000 I realized this last night. That was totally my issue. Thanks though!